# Thumbnail on PHP-CGI Nginx

Tags: php, nginx, thumbnails, fastcgi

Getting Issue on Thumbnail. i am now using Centos, FAST-CGI, AND NGINX.

can not be display because it contains error.

URL

```
http://domain.com/image_products_thumb.phpsrc=7c885388d2584a80dd4bd5e21e14afd6.jpeg&x=90&y=52&f=0
```

I check error log got followings

`2014/01/28 08:22:01 [error] 1443#0: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: file in /usr/share/nginx/html/domainname.com/image_products_thumb.php(1) : on line 29" while reading response header from upstream, client: 39.48.144.170, server: www.domainname.com, request: "GET /image_products_thumb.php?src=7c885388d2584a80dd4bd5e21e14afd6.jpeg&x=90&y=52&f=0 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "www.domain.com"`

i am using

```
http://mightystuff.net/php-thumbnail-script
```

Waiting for reply

Comment: I think your issue is a php issue more than an nginx issue, it said line 29 in the php file, what does that line say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct, I took a look on the PHP file and I think you just named a parameter wrong, try using `file` instead of `src`

`image_products_thumb.php?`**`file`**`=7c885388d2584a80dd4bd5e21e14afd6.jpeg&....`

Comment: Your Answer is Correct! :)